# Telethon python ошибка многопоточности

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, telethon

Необходимо пройтись по чатам группам и каналам и спарсить сообщения и детали этих групп/ каналов и т.д

Проблема заключается в том, что для получения деталей групп, имеется некоторый лимит на аккаунт, после превышения лимита, нельзя получить информацию из других групп на сутки.

Отсюда выходит, что нужно использовать несколько аккаунтов.
В качестве библиотеки использую Telethon.

```
def create_client(number):
    client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()

def main():
    load_numbers(filename_numbers)
    load_excel(filename_excel)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(create_client, numbers):
            pass
```

1. Мы загружаем из текстового файла список телефонов.
2. Создаем количество потоков (в данном случае до 8) и передаем название метода и список телефонов.
3. Должен создаться пул потоков (2, так 2 телефона в списке), которые должны создать соединение.
   Но выкидывает ошибку:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 149, in 
           main()
         File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 65, in main
           for _ in executor.map(create_client, numbers):
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
           yield fs.pop().result()
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 425, in result
           return self.**get_result()
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
           raise self._exception
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
           result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
         File "D:/Git/telegram/telegram_new.py", line 58, in create_client
           client = TelegramClient(number, api_id, api_hash)
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 171, in __init**
           self._loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
         File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
           % threading.current_thread().name)
       RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'

Что я делаю не так? (P.S. Отредактируйте вставленный код, он у меня не редактируется)

**Update:**

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as pool:
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=False)
    # Создаём клиентскую сессию
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as client:
        # Создаём корневую футуру
        initial_future = loop.create_future()
        # Помещаем в неё ссылки, с которых начнём парсить
        initial_future.set_result(root_urls)
        # Передаём эту футуру в сопрограмму обхода ссылок
        # вместе с пулом потоков и клиентской сессией
        await crawl(initial_future, client, pool)
```

Comment: Зачем вам многопоточность, если telethon асинхронный?

Comment: @andreymal по вашему мнению нельзя асинхронные засунуть в отдельные потоки? Смотрите код

Comment: Можно конечно, но на вопрос вы не ответили — зачем? Асинхронщина для того и существует, чтобы можно было выполнять много задач в **одном** потоке

Comment: @andreymal чтобы быстрее обрабатывать программу, так как даже во время отправки запросов, сначала притормаживается на 27 секунд потом, на 40с, а потом на сутки. В это время мы можем от другого аккаунта делать запросы, не?

Comment: О каких притормаживаниях речь?

Comment: @andreymal Ну например: telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 46883 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest). Или вот при преодолении определенного количества запросов (потом он увеличивается до суток): 2018-12-22 19:02:19,463 INFO:Sleeping for 53s on flood wait

Comment: А, ну то есть telethon притормаживает за вас, понятно. Только притормажиает же он асинхронно, вам ничего не мешает запустить несколько асинхронных задач на нескольких аккаунтах в одном потоке. Зачем здесь нужны потоки — по-прежнему непонятно. Если вы не слышали про ensure_future, значит вы, видимо, не знаете основ asyncio, и я рекомендую вам почитать учебники и документацию модуля asyncio, прежде чем продолжать с этим вопросом

Comment: @andreymal ну telethon уже вроде на asyncio написан, мне поверх его еще задач писать свои future? к тому же у меня будут cpu-bound действия, поэтому я и хотел в потоках делать

Comment: Свои future однозначно правильнее, чем свои потоки. Вот cpu-bound действия и выпихивайте в потоки, а работу с аккаунтами не надо

Comment: @andreymal а у вас не будет достойного примера, а то у меня пример связан с тем, что в каждом потоке, создаются свои future

Comment: Из описания вопроса я вашей задачи всё равно не понял и достойного примера не будет, но наверно что-то вроде `def create_client` заменить на `async def create_client` и вместо отдельного потока пихать его в `for number in numbers: fut = asyncio.ensure_future(create_client(numbers))` (а потом можно какой-нибудь asyncio.wait, но за этим в учебники и документацию)

Answer (score 1):

Я столкнулся с подобной ситуацией.
Заранее скажу, что меня несколько смущает "упаковка" вызова async методов в отдельный loop и проблему нужно решать иначе. Однако, отвечая на ваш вопрос, мне показался полезным [вот этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683173/10504918).

Мысль в том, чтобы создать еще один loop и в нем выполнить async метод, в котором вызывать await методы.

```
import asyncio

def func(message):
    async def main(key):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        client = client(key)
        await client.do_something()

        # Не забывайте разблокировать бд!
        await client.disconnect()

    # Создание нового loop
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    loop.run_until_complete(main('key'))
    loop.close()
```